# Is update to Windows 10 FCU frozen or just taking too long?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, freeze

I have a VirtualBox VM with Windows 10 that I only use every few weeks. I checked for updates today, and among other things asked me to upgrade windows saying it would take a long time. I decided to proceed with the update.

Before the "big upgrade" to what I believe to be Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, the OS updated a few things and I had to reboot. I went again to the update window and clicked restart, because it asked me to restart again. This time, there was some percentage values passing by, the machine then rebooted, and got stuck on the windows logo screen.

The VM has been stuck here for at least 2 hours but one of the CPU cores allocated to the machine is still showing 100% usage. I'm not sure whether I should hard reset the machine or wait because the CPU is showing the VM is doing something. I assume the update might take longer on a VM than on bare hardware... but two hours?

Any idea on what can I do?

Is there a shortcut to make the logo go away and actually show some feedback to know what the operating system is doing? (In Linux you can usually press a key to drop from the logo to a screen showing logs, but I have little experience with Windows.)

[image]

---

**Update 1:** I tried to shutdown the machine and got the message "*You are trying to shutdown the guest with the ACPI power button. This is currently not possible because the guest does not support software shutdown.*" So I went forward with a hard reset. The VM rebooted, the logo popped up again with some loading circular symbol that didn't show up before, and I was able to log into windows without any problems.

**Update 2:** There are more pending updates. It is now downloading "*Feature update to Windows 10, version 1703.*" According to the update history, what caused problems appears to be related to Windows 10 version 1607.

Comment: 1703 isn't the Fall Creators Update.....But, yes, the update clearly failed the first time.